react.js, video won't play on mobile
I made a react web which has a video as background image. It works on PC but not on mobile, at least not on my iphone.  After searching for hours, edited autoplay, playinline etc. in several different ways, nothing changes. On mobile the web only shows an empty background.
I use absolute position and zIndex to make it run as a background image.
My code is as below.

      <video
        id="video"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        autoPlay="autoplay"
        playsInLine="playsinline"
        loop="true"
        muted="true"
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          zIndex: -1,
          opacity: 0.5,
          objectFit: "cover",
        }}
        src={bgv}
        type="video/mp4"
      ></video>


its playsInline i guess not playsInLine ,, and did u try adding preload="auto" ?

A few issues here.

You're mixing up the JS string "true" with the JS boolean true. But, you don't even need to specify {true}; just putting the tags makes them default read as true
You need playsInline (lowercase L), not playsInLine
type should be applied to a nested source tag

Try ChatGPT for basic syntax mistakes like this.
Also, use Devtools to inspect the plain HTML video. There, you can see if attributes you tried to apply were correctly rendered. (But note that muted may not show even when applied.)
Corrected:
      <video
        id="video"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        autoPlay
        playsInline
        loop
        muted
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          zIndex: -1,
          opacity: 0.5,
          objectFit: "cover",
        }}
      > 
        <source src={bgv} type="video/mp4" />
      </video>

More troubleshooting:

Make sure the video encoding is H.264 (required by iOS). You can check by right-clicking it and looking at its Properties (Windows) or Get Info -> More Info (Mac). If it's not, you can use ffmpeg to change it.

Right click and open your video in a new tab on your live site. Copy the URL and see if the video plays when you go directly to that URL on mobile. If it doesn't even work there, you have one of two likely issues (in my experience). Either the video itself is messed up, or there's some disagreement between the React import or bundling method and mobile. You can pin it down by trying a video you know works in your local code.

Log the video error on mobile. If you can't access the console on mobile, a trick I use is setting the error in state, then displaying it in text in the actual page. Add to your video onError={handleError} and the below code, then add {error} somewhere prominent in your page.
 const [error, setError] = useState("");

 const handleError = (e) => {
 const errorObj = e.target.error;
 const errorMessage = `Error Code: ${errorObj.code}, Message: ${errorObj.message}`;
 setError(errorMessage);
 };



